# Dynamically create div into a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have many todo items stored in a XML file, I will create a div for each item to present them on the page. And according the type of each item, they will be put to different containers.

Now my question is how to make these dynamically created divs constraint into their container?
Anyone can help me out?

Now I get data from XML file and can create items onto the page, but the jquery append method will make the new added item in a regular order, what I want is the items are wrap together with container, like the image below, so the new added items wont enlarge the container.
[image]

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I'd use a switch statement. Depending the case > you put them in a specific container

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
/* Insert 'childtodoid' at the end of 'parentdivid' */
$('#childtodoid').appendTo('#parentdivid');
```

Comment: Hi @Francisco Presencia, the problem is there may be more than one todo item. I dont know how to arrange them on the page.

Comment: So you want each to be displayed at a slightly different position? Also, not to alter the size, you should use CSS `position`, for example, you can use absolute positioning for the todo items (remember to make the parent `position: relative;` then).